# Save same object in different tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In my project I have a lot of listing tables (all are the exactly same structure) where I store all dropdown options. For each table I have an history table to track all changes.

I want to create generic functions for insert or update a record in the main table and add a new record in the history table.

In SQLite I'm using something like

```
    public int SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : IMyEntity {
        lock (locker) {
            if (item.Id != 0) {
                database.Update(item);
                return item.Id;
            }
            else {
                return database.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't do that with EF. The database is MySQL.

Comment: of course you can't map the same type to different tables - since you always map the type, EF has no way to figure out which table to use. If you want to say it, that is the problem of ORM - they have to know which type to map to which table.

Answer (score 0):

While this is difficult (or perhaps impossible) with EF it's absolutely trivial using [Drapper](https://github.com/sextondjc/drapper).

The method would likely look something like:

```
public T Save<T> (T item) where T : IMyEntity
{
    return _commander.Execute(item) ? item : null; 
}
```

Where `_commander` is an instance of Drapper's IDbCommander. From this point you'd supply the SQL to either insert or update the item in the database & put that SQL in your config.

Really simple, really fast, fully testable.

Answer (score 0):

About adapting your code to EF this shoud work if you are working with attached entities

```
public int SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : IMyEntity {
    lock (locker) {
        if (item.Id != 0) {
            context.Set(typeof(T)).Add(item);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return item.Id;
    }
}
```